# Mysql query select from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database

table `question (id, content, ...)`
table `answer (question_id, user_id, content,...)`
table `reaction (question_id, user_id, ...)`

I can get info of questions and count num_reaction by sql "`SELECT q.*, COUNT(r.user_id) AS num_reaction FROM question q LEFT JOIN reaction r ON q.id = r.question_id GROUP BY q.id ORDER BY q.id DESC`"

--
Please help me query to select all from table question and COUNT(reaction.user_id) AS num_reaction and COUNT(answer.user_id) AS num_reply

Answer (score 0):

Below the table create statements is the SQL that I would use. You can also use temporary table or the WITH clause.

```sql
CREATE TABLE question (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    content varchar(255) 
);

CREATE TABLE answer (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id INT(6),
    user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED,
    content varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE reaction (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id INT(6),
    user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED
)

SELECT Q1.content, Q1.countAns, Q2.countReact
FROM
( select q.*, count(r.user_id) countAns 
    from question q 
    left join reaction r on q.id = r.question_id 
    group by q.id, q.content ) Q1
JOIN
( select q.*, count(r.user_id) countReact from question q left join answer r on q.id = r.question_id group by q.id, q.content ) Q2
on Q1.id = Q2.id;
```